# Javascript: using Regex to search for any four digits in a row

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a function that confirms if a string contains any four digits in a row (for the purposes of finding a date).

The code I have is:

```
string.search(^\d{4}$)
```

Any advice?  I'm really inexperienced with Regex.  I'd also appreciate any input on where to learn to use Regex more effectively.

Comment: It doesn't work because of your [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is

```
/\d{4}/.test(yourString)
```

which returns a boolean.

Note that

- the ^ and $ you were using match the start and end of the string. They would have been useful to test if a string was *only* made of 4 digits.
- `search` is useful when you want the position of the match. In your case `test` is simpler.

To go further, I recommend [this good and concise documentation on regexes in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)